# How to leave space between different tables

Tags: tables

In my document i have several tables like this

```
    \begin{tabular}{l c c}
        ...
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c}
        ...
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        ...
    \end{tabular}
```

but they all show up right beneath each other in my documents and i can't figure out how to leave blank space in between them

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How much vertical whitespace would you like to insert between the `tabular` environments?

Comment: Space i can figure out i just needed the command that leaves the space because all i could find by googling was commands about horizontal space not vertical

Comment: You might be interested in `\smallskip`, `\medskip` and `\bigskip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
    \begin{tabular}{l c c}
    ...a&b&c
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10mm}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c}
    ...x&y&z
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10mm}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    ...1&2&3
\end{tabular}
```